# Programmatically injecting command into Python Cmd's cmdloop

Tags: python

Using Python Cmd2 module (inherits from Cmd) to create a MyCmd CLI for my program.  In most cases, I am just using my script normally with the built-in commands.  The ‘quit’ command is implemented to do some cleanup for the script and subsequently exit.  The Cmd2 module waits for input via the raw_input.

In a specific case, I want to programmatically invoke ‘quit’ instead of issuing it at the command line.  This is done via a separate thread where a REST API translates a ‘quit’ POST to invoke quit on the main thread of the script.

I found a couple of SO questions that want to do something similar, but not exactly like this.  I tried to follow the below example, but it didn’t work:
   [Python StringIO - selectively place data into stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480632/python-stringio-selectively-place-data-into-stdin)

Then I tried something simple.  Basically did the below from the thread:

```
sys.stdin = StringIO('quit\n')
sys.stdin.flush()
```

It seems that the word 'quit' was injected, but the script would not do its clean exit.  However, I could go back to the command line and simply press Enter, which would trigger the cleanup and exit process.  Not sure why ‘\n’ was not being interpreted as Enter.

My cmd is simply invoked in the below manner:

```
mycmd = MyCmd()
mycmd.cmdloop()
```

How can I properly inject ‘quit’ into the cmdloop of Cmd?

Comment: is it possible you are looking to override [`Cmd.postcmd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.postcmd)?

Comment: From what I can tell, calling any method directly won't work because they get called outside the cmdloop.  Hence, the return of True (to end cmdloop) doesn't get passed to cmdloop, rather to the calling code which runs outside of cmdloop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the cmd.onecmd("quit") method? I think it can be used to inject commands in the interpreter.